# How to download a web.config file via the VSO rest api from a TFVC repository

Tags: rest, azure-devops

The visual studio online rest api has a rest call to download the contents of a file in a TFVC repository. I want to download the latest version of all my TFVC repositories to have an on-premise back-up of all our projects.

This APi works great except for one type of file: web.config. When I want to download the web.config file I get a 404 statuscode. All other filetypes (also log4net.config and web.release.config) download correctly and I also get a 202 there. I have the correct permission to download the file and the file also exist.

I use the api as documented here: https://www.visualstudio.com/integrate/api/tfvc/items#Getafile

As you can see the path to the file in the repository is part of the URL. I think with this syntax, Visual Studio Online default security comes in way of files like web.config. In e.g. IIS the download of a web.config file is also disabled. For our git repositories this is no problem because that api doesn't include the path to the file in the url but as parameter of the url.

Is there a way around this? An undocumented feature?

When I see this documentation https://www.visualstudio.com/integrate/api/tfvc/items#Getaspecificversion it mentions:

> You can indicate which version to get when you get a file, **zip a folder**, or get item metadata.

That zip a folder part is not (yet) documented. Does anybody of you know how to call that part of the api? That would also be a workaround for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is now possible when you use the path as query parameter

> This format should be used for certain files (like web.config) that are not accessible by using the path as part of the URL due to the default ASP .NET protection. The response is a stream (application/octet-stream) that contains the contents of the file.

```
http://fabrikam-fiber-inc.visualstudio.com/defaultcollection/_apis/tfvc/items?path=$/fabrikam-fiber-tfvc/website/website/web.config&api-version={version}
```

The above quote is from the documentation after this is added: https://www.visualstudio.com/integrate/api/tfvc/items#Getafile.